# In a QFormLayout with labels with enabled word-wrap, layout gets borked one out of 4 times

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QFormLayout`. The labels on the left vary wildly in length depending on the active language. To work around this, I enabled word wrap on each of the labels. Most of the time this works fine, but sometimes I get strange artifacts:

[image: Screenshot showing a few problems]

What is going on with "Option de intermedio"? Why did it decide to break that one, but not the one above? Why is the text cut off, when it's clearly fine in the row two rows down ("Remover ...")?

Most importantly, what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the minimum size is not correctly calculated for QLabels with word wrap enabled. You should override minimumSizeHint() and calculate the height of the text manually using QFontMetrics

by the way, you will need to use the version of QFontMetrics that takes also flags and pass it Qt::TextWordWrap

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-6